# MySQL database server v.s. Phpmyadmin

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

Can anyone "PLEASE" answer these two questions :

1- What is the difference between MySQL database server and Phpmyadmin ?

2- can I make a connection from a java software to a phpmyadmin database using JDBC-driver ? and how ?

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1- What is the difference between MySQL database server and Phpmyadmin ?

mySQL is a database server. phpMyAdmin is a client tool to access a mySQL database, written in PHP and used in a browser.

> 2- can I make a connection from a java software to a phpmyadmin database using JDBC-driver ? and how ?

No, but you should be able to make a connection to a mySQL database. As to how... I don't know  but I'm sure there is reference info for this.

**Update**: See [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/):

> JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J)

Comment: "one's the car, the other's the driver"

Comment: "one's the server, the other's the client"